# Воспрещен или запрещен - как правильно?

Tags: орфография

Как мне писать правильно на дверце: Посторонним вход воспрещен или запрещен?

Заранее благодарю.

Answer (score 4):

ЗАПРЕТИТЬ,  Не разрешить делать что-л.; воспретить. Врачи запретили больному курить. З. шуметь в коридоре.

ВОСПРЕТИТЬ,  Офиц. Запретить. Вход строго воспрещён.

Различие стиля определяется разным значением приставок.

Приставка ЗА используется для образования глаголов совершенного вида и в данном случае имеет значение "доведение действия до результативного конца".

Приставка ВОЗ используется с тем же значением, но эта приставка может дополнительно обозначать действие, направленное кверху (возвести, воспарить), а также внезапное, интенсивное, резкое действия  (возликовать, возомнить).

Отсюда следует ее применение в стилях речи, отличных от нейтрального.

Comment: Интересно, в каком словаре эти два слова определяются через друг друга?

Comment: На Грамоте.ру: Большой толковый словарь русского языка.
Гл. ред. С. А. Кузнецов.

Comment: Вам это не кажется странным? «А это как Б, но неофициально. Б это официальная версия А».

Comment: Кажется немного странным, надо было оформить так: ЗАПРЕТИТЬ, Не разрешить делать что-л.; воспретить (офиц.).

Answer (score 3):

Корректны оба варианта. Первый относится к нейтральному стилю, второй - к официальному.